# Where can I get historical P/E ratio data of american stock?

Tags: data, market-data

I'm looking for P/E ratio of `IBM` or `APPL` (American nasdaq stock(?)) for past few years but I can not find it even I searched it in Google.

I read API docs of `quandl` but can not find it, either.

Since my native language is not an English, I wrote this post to getting some help.

Thanks

Comment: @AlexC "Past few years"

Comment: Does yahoo finance works for you?¿

Comment: @arodrisa I thought yahoo finance only has current P/E, not last 5 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WolframAlpha has free historical P/E ratios (with Facebook as example stock).

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%2Fe+facebook](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%2Fe%20facebook)

There's also YCharts which has a free week trial and very good historical P/E graphs.

https://ycharts.com

Comment: "free"? I have to subscribe it if I want to download it T_T.. Anyway Thanks :)